PowerBI - How to pivot answer lists to column answers
In PowerBI, I have a data table which includes a question column and an associated answer column.
In the answer column there are a mixture of lists (lists may contain one or more answers) and non-list values.
The question column should be pivoted so that each question is a new column with the associated answers from the answer column. There are also a number of other columns in the data table I want to keep in the output data table.
Starting example data table format

Desired example data table format

Please see the answer below for the workaround I used.

Explain please what " there are a mixture of lists" means. Will there be multiple answers just in Declaration or for any question field.  What do you want to do with them? Expand them into one per row?

Kindly edit your question to provide sufficient information as text which can be copy/pasted so we can reproduce your issue. Suggest you read read the HELP pages for information as to How to Ask a Good Question, and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and also the thread at Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

Hello and thank you for the comments.  Ultimately, I resolved the query today by separating each question and answer combination in to their own dfs.  Expanded the lists in each new df and then pivoted the values.  Thereafter the dfs were merged in to a single df.

The query was resolved as follows:
1/. Separate each question and answer combination in to their own dfs.
2/. Expand the lists (where present) in each new df.
3/. Pivot the fields in each df.
4/. Merge the separate dfs in to a common df using a shared key column (in this example the 'Code' column) keeping the relevant columns in the new common df.
